# How to concatenate iteratives from lines in a file into one string?

Tags: python-2.7

How do we concatenate substrings extracted from iterative lines into one single string? Many thanks for your help.

Suppose I have the file text.txt

```
One is 1
Two is 2
Three is 3
```

I want to extract from this file a single string of "One, Two, Three"
I have tried perhaps mistakenly line.replace() and rstrip() neither of which gave the desired output. My codes are shown below.

```
def getnum():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line.replace("\n", ",")
            col=line.split(" is ")
            num=col[0]
            print(num)
    f.close()
    return

def getnum2():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            col=line.split(" is ")
            num=col[0] + ","
            num.rstrip("\n")
            print(num)
    f.close()
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #getnum()
    getnum2()
```

The actual result I got if I tried the first function was

```
One
Two
Three
```

The actual result I got if I tried the second function was

```
One,
Two,
Three,
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file size is not large, and you want to store the required words in a list then you can join them as :

```
def getnum():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        word_list = []
        for line in f:
            col = line.split(" is ")
            word_list.append(col[0])
        print((", ").join(word_list))
```

Or you can print as you read the file using the following:

for python2:

```
def getnum():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        flag = False
        for line in f:
            if flag:
                print ",",
            flag = True
            col=line.split(" is ")
            num=col[0]
            print num,
    f.close()
    return
```

for python3:

```
def getnum():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
        flag = False
        for line in f:
            if flag:
                print (",", end=" ")
            flag = True
            col=line.split(" is ")
            num=col[0]
            print (num, end="")
    f.close()
    return
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer. I loved the string.join() and will read into it.